# iOS WebView Page Load Error

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cordova

While loading a page in the `UIWebView` I am getting following error in the application

```
2013-08-21 18:48:37.841 iOS6PG2.7[7886:707] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

**(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)**

I am unable to find what is the error code -999.

Comment: [`NSURLErrorDomain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40). Error -999 is `NSURLErrorCancelled`

Comment: Didnt get it. NSURLErrorCancelled? How to solve it.

Comment: `NSURLErrorCancelled` error may occur if an another request is made before the previous request of `UIWebView` is completed. Check your code for such scenarios.